# How to check if foreign key exists?

Tags: django, django-views, foreign-keys

Here I have a model called `Staff` which has OneToOne relation with django `User` model and ForeignKey relation to the `Organization` model.Here while deleting the organization I want to check if the organization exists in Staff model or not .If it exists in Staff model then i don't want to delete but if it doesn't exists in other table then only I want to delete.

How can I do it ?

I got this error with below code:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

models.py

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique_with='id', populate_from='name')
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to='logo', blank=True, null=True)

class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                                     related_name='staff')
```

views.py

```
def delete_organization(request, pk):
    organization = get_object_or_404(Organization, pk=pk)
    if organization in organization.staff.all().exists():
        messages.error(request,"Sorry can't be deleted.")
        return redirect('organization:view_organizations')
# also tried
# if organization in get_user_model().objects.filter(staff__organization=organizatin).exists():
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'delete_single' in request.POST:
        organization.delete()
        messages.success(request, '{} deleted.'.format(organization.name))
        return redirect('organization:view_organizations')
```

Comment: Please can you show your full error trace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The check should be:

```
def delete_organization(request, pk):
    organization = get_object_or_404(Organization, pk=pk)
    if organization.staff.exists():
        messages.error(request, "Sorry can't be deleted.")
        return redirect('organization:view_organizations')
    # ...
```

You can however optimize the above, by doing proper filtering in the `get_object_or_404` already:

```
def delete_organization(request, pk):
    organization = get_object_or_404(Organization, pk=pk, is_staff__isnull=True)
    # ...
```

This will then raise a 404 in case the organization does not exist, or the organization exists, but has still some staff.

Based on the logic you wrote, you want to prevent that you can delete an organization if there is still staff. You can set such logic in the *model* layer as well, by using `models.PROTECT` as `on_delete` handler:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, related_name='staff')
```

Now Django will help you enforce that you do not, by accident, remove an `Organization` where there is still related staff, this makes it more safe.

Answer (score 0):

beside the answer of Mr @Willem you can change your model Fk to `on_delete=models.PROTECT` then create a view like this :

```
from django.db.models.deletion import ProtectedError
def delete_organization(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Organization,id=id)
    try:
        obj.delete()
        return return_to_somewhere
except ProtectedError:
    return 'show some error message'
```

Answer (score 0):

To see if the foreignkey exists in template:

***index.html***

```html
{% if organization.staff %}
   <p>staff exists</p>
{% endif %}
```

> Instead of `organization.staff.exists()` it is `organization.staff`, when writing in Django Template code

---

The reason I write this answer in this question was because this was the first Stack Overflow question that came up when searching for "Django template see if foreignkey exist" on DuckDuckGo.